Typescript declaration file just creating secondary definition instead of replacing interface
I'm using mongoose-delete and its types package @types/mongoose-delete. There is a problem with one of their interface declarations, so I've tried to augment it like so...
// mongoose-soft-delete.d.ts
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import 'mongoose-delete';

declare module 'mongoose-delete' {
  interface SoftDeleteModel<
    T,
  //.. the rest of the owl
  >
}

It's only half working in that - now I have two definitions for SoftDeleteModel. How do I get it to replace the other instead? The original declaration is like
import mongoose = require("mongoose");

declare namespace MongooseDelete {
    interface SoftDeleteModel<
        T extends Omit<mongoose.Document, "delete">,
    // ...
  }
}

When I try to include the namespace value, it does not work at all.

This question is similar but not the same to this one otherwise I'd be on my merry way. It describes an issue with duplicating the type and not "how do I do this".

I think I may understand why it doesn't work - perhaps because the generic types are not the same, it does not override it, but provides an overloaded definition..

Unfortunately TS doesn't let you "replace" definitions this way unless you actually modify the types in the files you're using. You are trying to use declaration merging, but as you saw, it only adds things, not replaces them. The other question's answers describe different approaches to achieve the behavior you're looking for (although it's unfortunately somewhat painful). If you still don't think this question is a duplicate, please [edit] to explain how none of the answers there met your needs when you tried to apply them.

I'm sorry you feel that this question was closed unfairly. Right now we disagree about whether this question duplicates that one. If you [edit] to a form I agree is significantly different (so that the answers to one don't answer the other) then I'd be happy to vote to reopen. You're also welcome to vote to reopen. It is helpful to assume that people are interacting in good faith.

Na, it's quite widely known that this place is a toxic, gatekeepers paradise of what it once was a decade ago. I don't know that I've opened a question in the last 6 years that didn't get closed in 5 minutes because someone mentioned the same keyword in a question. Like, you know I see the related questions, right? You know I spent hours researching already, right? It's just never enough for this site - yet I see the dumbest "what is a pointer" questions get through all the time. Whatever.

The linked question has answers that describe what you should do. Someone with your problem finds your question and then is forwarded to the other one and gets their answer. That is the intent of closing things as duplicates. I get that you don’t agree with that, but I promise that I’m trying to do pro-social things here. You can edit, you can vote to reopen, or if you think I’ve done something against the rules or spirit of the rules you can maybe flag me for moderation. Anyway it seems we’re probably at an impasse so I’ll disengage. Sorry this experience was unpleasant for you.
